# Change to RabbitMQ Queue policy

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to change a policy value or add a new policy to an existing RabbitMQ queue?

I have existing queue to which I would like to add the "x-max-length" policy.

Must I delete the queue and recreate it, or can I add this policy via the rabbitmqcl command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, once you declared queue you cannot re-declare it, so yes, you have to recreate (delete and then declare) queue with required arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I have a RabbitMQ `3.5.7` Cluster of 4 nodes with high availability queues. I wanted to make some of the existing queues from HA mode to non-HA mode. So, I tried to update the policy.

So I deleted the old policy and applied new policy on the queues and It reflected immediately. I need not re-create the queues to update the policy.

P.S. The new policy applied immediately on all the queues, without re-creating them.

Comment: Same here, using RabbitMQ `3.7.8`. I created a policy with `ha-mode: all` and it immediately applied to all queues matching the policy pattern.